# Unity crashed after upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: 12.04, unity, 12.10

I just upgraded my 12.04 to 12.10 and after restart I can't do anything.
I can just use the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). I can't move windows, there is no window bar, no top panel, no unity launcher.

What I should do?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My PCs properties:
Intel® Pentium(R) CPU G840 @ 2.80GHz × 2
GeForce GTS 450/PCIe/SSE2

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide us with some info about your system.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is also what I am experiencing... For me the problem is that the graphics driver claims to support OpenGL and GLX but lacks important features for Unity. Due to some changes in Unity it won't fall back to slow mode automatically. Try to add the following file:

```
# /etc/X11/Xsession.d/99try_slow_mode
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1
```

Then reboot and see if it works. This essentially forces all applications to fall back to software 3D rasterizer which is slow. I think they are currently trying to add some smarter fallback and I'd like to see that it gets fixed.

It also looks like there is currently nothing one could do to disable some effects in Unity so it will work with implementations of older graphics drivers.

To revert back simply delete the file and reboot.

**Amendment:** Just in case someone wants to collect this, my GPU is AMD Mobility Radeon 7500 [RV200]...

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply! I am quite new in Ubuntu actually. I dont know what I should do, which file I can add? I suppose that this is not command

Comment: I found the solution.  
I just install my graphics(which was not after upgrade) with command:  
  
apt-get install nvidia-current  
  
Some of settings are gone(such as window transparency, shortcuts) so have to customize my ubuntu again.  
  
Anyway, thanks for help!